# Does the Watson Text-to-Speech service in Bluemix work for mobile apps?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

Why doesn't the Watson Text-To-Speech service on Bluemix work for mobile devices? Is this a common issue for outputstream data coming from the server? Thanks!

Edit: Sry, somebody have changed my question totally. I am talking about Text-to-Speech

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text To Speech works in Android, and there is a SDK you can use.

http://watson-developer-cloud.github.io/java-wrapper/

For example, to get all the voices you can do:

```
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.text_to_speech.v1.TextToSpeech;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.text_to_speech.v1.model.VoiceSet;

TextToSpeech service = new TextToSpeech();
service.setUsernameAndPassword("<username>", "<password>");

VoiceSet voices = service.getVoices();
System.out.println(voices);
```

where `username` and `password` are the credentials you get in Bluemix when you bind the service. You can learn more about the Text to Speech methods by looking at the javadocs [here](http://watson-developer-cloud.github.io/java-wrapper/docs/index.html?com/ibm/watson/developer_cloud/text_to_speech/v1/TextToSpeech.html).

It was released today and I made it so let me know if you find any issue.

Answer (score 1):

The Watson Speech-To-Text service is a REST API.  You will need to call the REST API from your mobile app.  For more info about the REST API check [out the API docs](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/apis/#!/speech-to-text).

Comment: It is not. Maybe it depends on the device type, but even the demo on Bluemix is working only for notebook/pc web browser, not for mobile web browser. When I open it with tablet or mobile and try to run the demo text to speech is not working. I mean I can't hear anything

Comment: Jeff is correct. The Watson Text-to-Speech service is just a REST API, however the demo uses client-side javascript that only works in certain browsers. It is up to the developer to make sure that their application works on all browsers that they intend their users to utilize.

Comment: ok I see, so probably, the iPads, and some older mobile phones will execute the javscript differenly if they do at all. Ok guys thank you, you have pointed me to the right direction, thanks!

Comment: @jeff what is the complete REST API url to call? the doc stated like synthesize?accept=audio%2Fflac&voice=en%2DUS%5FLisaVoice&&text= but never write down what is the complete url

Comment: @MarkThien this is a new question

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Watson Text-To-Speech for iOS devices it might be handy using [Watson-Developer-Cloud SDK for iOS](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/ios-sdk#text-to-speech) - you might checkout the example on my [blumarek.blogspot](http://ibm.biz/SwiftWatsonTTS), just simply build an app in XCode 7.3+:

#### step 1. use carthage to get all the dependencies:

(create a file cartfile in a project root directory and run the command *carthage update --platform iOS*)

```
$ cat > cartfile
# cartfile contents
github "watson-developer-cloud/ios-sdk"
```

and then you need to add the frameworks to the XCode project - check Step 3: Adding the SDK to the Xcode project on my blumareks.blogpost

#### step 2. add the code to call the Watson TTS and leverage AVFoundation

*(AVFoundation is being deprecated):*
- do not forget to add the Watson TTS service in Bluemix.net and get the credentials from it:

```
{
  "credentials": {
    "url": "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api",
    "username": "<service User name>",
    "password": "<password>"
  }
}
```

And the code is a plain one:

```
import UIKit

//adding Watson Text to Speech
import WatsonDeveloperCloud
//adding AVFoundation
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var speakText: UITextField!
override func viewDidLoad() {...}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {...}

@IBAction func speakButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    NSLog("speak button pressed, text to say: " + speakText.text!)
   //adding Watson service
    let service = TextToSpeech(username: "<service User name>", password: "<password>")
    service.synthesize(speakText.text!)
    {(data, error) in
        do {
            let audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(data: data!)
            audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            audioPlayer.play()
            sleep(10) //the thread needs to live long enough to say your text
        } catch {
            NSLog("something went terribly wrong")
        }
}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear if you are asking about the speech to text or vice versa.   The speech to text is covered in most of the questions above and can be referenced on the Watson site -

http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/speech-to-text.html

The Speech to Text service converts the human voice into the written word. This easy-to-use service uses machine intelligence to combine information about grammar and language structure with knowledge of the composition of the audio signal to generate a more accurate transcription. The transcription is continuously sent back to the client and retroactively updated as more speech is heard. Recognition models can be trained for different languages, as well as for specific domains.

Comment: How would I stream audio data to the REST api ?  Recording the audio in iOS, then sending it off for processing takes 5 seconds minimum for me , which is unfortunately too long.

Answer (score -1):

If you look at this github project https://github.com/FarooqMulla/BluemixExample/tree/master which uses the Old SDK

There is an example that uses the real time speech to text api which sends audio packets to bluemix and receives back the transcribed string in real time.

Beware as of 1/22/16 the new Swift based SDK is broken for this particular functionality.